# jQuery selector not working in different SharePoint environment

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have two different sharepoint 2013 dev environment A & B. the below function is working only in A.

```
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {

    // alert(userAccountName);

    var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");

    var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');

    var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");



    userAccountName.split(";").forEach(function (part) {

        if (part !== "" && part !== null) {

            //  alert(part);
            //
            _PeoplePickerEditer.val(part);

            var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];






            _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

        }

    });



}
```

This function used to populate SharePoint client people picker with list of users. where fieldName is the title attribute and userAccountName is a list of Domain\username semi column separated. 
the issue is in

```
var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");
```

this selector is not able to return the input control in the solution deployed in server B however it is working fine in server A.

Comment: Is the fieldName title attribute definitely the same for the inputs on server B?

Comment: Sure, the same solution with the same title attribute is deployed in both server

Comment: Im assuming jquery is working ok in server B - have you checked the console logs? There can sometimes be conflicts with mulitple jquery libraries.

Comment: Can you check the Sharepoint Version on both servers ?

Comment: We have different SharePoint 2013 versions but still this is not a clear reason of such jQuery behavior and the console log is not providing any errors or warnings